# How to get correct class element from HTML using VBA

Tags: html, vba, dom, ms-word, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to extract [this](https://www.google.co.in/patents/US6627754B2?cl=en) website using VBA

This is the HTML I want to Target

```
<div class="claim"> <div num="1" id="US-6627754-B2-CLM-00001" class="claim">
```

to get data for various numbers, only constant things is

```
<div class ="claims" and class ="claim"
```

rest of the html is dynamic.

following code just works fine for first element.

```
oHtml.getElementsByClassName("claim").Item.innerHTML
```

for this case

```
oHtml.getElementsByTagName("div")(90).innerHTML
```

also gives desired result.

I don't have basic knowledge of HTML or VBA.

I know that this is not correct as it gives duplicate entry one for div class="claim" and other for class="claim" and div(90) is not always constant.

How to just target

```
<div class = "claim"
```

Tried `oHtml.getElementsByTagName("div")(90).getElementsByClassName("claim").Item.innerHTML`
but did not gave results. For this specific website it is at div 90. again its not constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried finding ir by using the id as this is uniqe and can only be used once so you won't get duplicates ! On my phone atm so can't give eg if you need I will when on my computer! I'm studying both html and vba not a pro but I think I know what i'm doing!

Comment: If I Understood it correctly, for Me, id is dynamic for different addresses. The only constant thing is <div class = claim>.

Comment: Really because when I have been coding recently I have used a class to style a range of elements and then a id to differ between them!!?

Comment: For me the id is unique for one set of data. I don't know what will be the data on lending page. So what I want is to get oHtml.getElementsByTagName("div")(90).getElementsByClassName("claim").Item.innerHTML to work.